# angular form, what i have done wrong?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I'm new with angular forms, i'm trying to validate an email field, and sho a message if the input is invalid.

Ithinked to have do everything correctly, but the error message doesen't show.

```
        <form name="Login" novalidate>

      <div class="ama-col-sm-12 pad-top-20-xs form-group">
        <label class="copy-title mts-bold pad-bottom-10-xs d-block">E-MAIL</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="Login.userMail" required ng-class="{'invalidClass': Login.userMail.$invalid}">
        <div ng-show="Login.userMail.$invalid">
          Non va mica bene
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Can you tell me if in the markup there is something wrong please?

Comment: you are missing `name="userMail"` for `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put name attribute on your `email` input field and then use the field `name` while show/hide validation message.

Also make sure your form `name` and `ng-model` object shouldn't be the same otherwise it will get wiped off. In this case `Login` and ng-model's `Login` were conflicting.

```
<form name="Login" novalidate>

  <div class="ama-col-sm-12 pad-top-20-xs form-group">
    <label class="copy-title mts-bold pad-bottom-10-xs d-block">E-MAIL</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.userMail" required 
       ng-class="{'invalidClass': Login.email.$invalid}">
    <div ng-show="Login.email.$invalid">
      Non va mica bene
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `ng-class` still has `Login.userMail`.. :)